# Keeping elements in their relative position to the background when resizing window?

Tags: html, css, background, resize

I'd like the logo to "follow the movement" of the centered background (a picture) when resizing the window. Is it possible ? I've tried a lot of things, but couldn't get it.

**Background**

`div.container{
     width:1164px;
    height: 776px;
    margin:0px;
    border:none;
    line-height:150%;`

`background-image: url('background');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:left:45px;top:20px;

    }`

**Logo**

`<img style="position:fixed;left:45px;top:20px;" src="/logo" width="205"   height="234" alt="logo"/>`

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is being used? Also what exactly do you mean by follow the movement of the centered background, if you put the logo in the div container then it will stay with that div. Also if the div "container" is unique you may consider using it as a css id instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the content only horizontally you can try
div.container{margin:0 auto}
and put the background image on the body like this
body {background-image: url('background'); background-position: 50% 0px;}